# RestKit connection failure delegate

Tags: ios, web-services, delegates, restkit

I'm trying to test the behavior of my app when connection fails. I am testing on an iPad with wifi turned off. When Restkit attempts a web service call, I get the following error:

```
CPL[7713:6203] E restkit.network:RKRequest.m:545 Failed to send request to https://xxxxxxxx/APNS_WebService/rest/operations/initializeDevice?deviceID=c4a17f855d3cc824b174b71908480d4e505ebfb221cb4643da9270a07344c367 due to unreachable network.
```

The problem is that I would like to handle this situation in a delegate callback method, but none of the delegate methods are being called. I have set the delegate on the request, and have requestDidFailLoadWithError, requestDidCancelLoad, requestDidTimeout, and objectLoaderDidFailWithError implemented. None of these are called.

Why aren't my delegates being called?

**EDIT:** After setting a breakpoint inside RKRequest.m, I see that the following line is in fact being executed:

```
        [self performSelector:@selector(didFailLoadWithError:) withObject:error afterDelay:0];
```

However, my delegate methods are not getting called.

Here's where I set the delegate:

```
request = [client requestWithResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/initializeDevice?deviceID=%@",deviceID]];
request.delegate=self;
[request sendAsynchronously];
```

**EDIT 2:** Actually, the line in RKRequest.m that I posted above is just calling another method in RKRequest, except that it's not. Putting a breakpoint in didFailLoadWithError shows that this code is never reached. I don't get why that's not working.

Changing the performSelector to a regular method call appears on the surface to give me the behavior I'm looking for. Is this going to break anything? I guess I'm not sure why performSelector is being used to call a method in the same class.

**EDIT 3:** As requested, here's my delegate method:

```
-(void)request:(RKRequest *)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(error.domain);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",error.code]);
    NSLog(error.localizedDescription);
    NSLog(error.localizedFailureReason);

    [request reset];
    [request send];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

> Actually, the line in RKRequest.m that I posted above is just calling another method in RKRequest, except that it's not. Putting a breakpoint in didFailLoadWithError shows that this code is never reached. I don't get why that's not working.

This is really strange. I would try doing a full clean of the project and rebuild.

As to what entails a direct call instead of using `performSelector`, you can see that `afterDelay`:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(didFailLoadWithError:) withObject:error afterDelay:0];
```

this will make the `didFailLoadWithError:` method be called at the next iteration of the run loop. I would keep this way of calling it.

You could try, though, with this alternative:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^() { 
                       [self didFailLoadWithError:error]; } );
```

I would suggest setting a breakpoint inside of the RestKit method you are using (I suppose `sendAsynchronously`) and check what happens. If you look into the method definition, the call to the delegate is effectively there:

```
    } else {
        self.loading = YES;

        RKLogError(@"Failed to send request to %@ due to unreachable network. Reachability observer = %@", [[self URL] absoluteString], self.reachabilityObserver);
        NSString* errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The client is unable to contact the resource at %@", [[self URL] absoluteString]];
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  errorMessage, NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,
                                  nil];
        NSError* error = [NSError errorWithDomain:RKErrorDomain code:RKRequestBaseURLOfflineError userInfo:userInfo];
        [self performSelector:@selector(didFailLoadWithError:) withObject:error afterDelay:0];
    }
```

Comment: why don´t you step into `didFailLoadWithError:` to see exactly why the delegate method is not called? it may depend on the cache policy you chose...

Comment: could you also post the definition of your delegate method `request:didFailLoadWithError:`?

Comment: It looks like didFailLoadWithError: isn't actually being called for some reason...I mean the performSelector statement is executed, but the code isn't reached.

Comment: Also, is there a reason they're using performSelector there rather than just calling didFailLoadWithError?

Comment: The alternative you posted works. Does that provide identical functionality to the other call?

Comment: yes, it does. anyway, it is a real mystery why `performSelector` does not work. the only explanation would be that the `performSelector` call is cancelled through `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget`, but I could not find it used.

Comment: another explanation is that all this processing happens on a separate thread without its own run loop; that would make sense.

Comment: I think I'll move forward with this solution and hope nothing breaks. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Note that `dispatch_get_current_queue()` is deprecated since iOS 6.0